# Reset Drag and Drop Game - ActionScript 3 - Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, reset

I am working on a Drag and Drop game in ActionScript 3.

When I click for a new game, the objects stay matched, not in their original position.

How to reset its positions when a new game starts?

```
var dragArray:Array = [square_word, circle_word, triangle_word];
var matchArray:Array = [squareMatch, circleMatch, triangleMatch];
var posArray:Array = [ {x:276, y:207}, {x:443, y:207}, {x:107, y:207} ];

var dragGame:DragGame = new DragGame(stage, dragArray, matchArray, posArray);

dragGame.addEventListener(DragGame.MATCH_MADE, onMatch);
dragGame.addEventListener(DragGame.NO_MATCH, onFlub);
dragGame.addEventListener(DragGame.ALL_DONE, onDone);

function onMatch(event:Event):void {
var matchSound:Sound = new MatchSound();
matchSound.play();
}
function onFlub(event:Event):void {
var flubSound:Sound = new FlubSound();
flubSound.play();
}
function onDone(event:Event):void {
var applause:Sound = new Applause();
applause.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the posArray is the original positions of square_word, circle_word, triangle_word, you just need to set x and y of objects in dragArray with posArray  in the constructor of DragGame ;

If not

Use a variable originalPos to keep the original positions of objects in dragArray before star first game. originalPos  could be a dictionary, like

```
originalPos[square_word] = {x:100, y:100};
```

When you start a new game, pass the originalPos to the contructor of DragGames, then you can set the x and y of quare_word, circle_word, triangle_word with the data in originalPos.